# Python: How to obtain headers and payload information for requests.Session()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, http-headers, python-requests, payload

In Python, how can I obtain `headers` and `payload` information for a particular website to make requests via `requests.Session()`?

e.g.:

```
headers = {
            'Host': 'www.testsite.com',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Proxy-Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-us',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Origin': 'http://www.testsite.com',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11D257',
            'Referer': 'http://www.testsite.com/mobile'
}
```

Thank you in advance and will be sure to upvote and accept answer

Comment: You build your own headers to be whatever you want, so I'm not sure what you mean by "how do I obtain headers?".  Do you mean "How do I discover what headers the host _wants_ to receive?"

Answer (score 0):

Most of those headers are automatically supplied by the `requests` module. Here is an example:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set?name=joe')
    r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies')
    pprint(dict(r.request.headers))

assert r.json()['cookies']['name'] == 'joe'
```

The output of the `pprint()` call is this:

```
{'Accept': '*/*',
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'Cookie': 'name=joe',
 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.9.1'}
```

As you can see, `s.get()` fills in several headers.

Comment: Thanks for the response! how about as for payload for a specific route, e.g. `http://www.testsite.com/students.json`, and how do you actually find out what routes are available for a site in the first place? And why does it have e.g. `students.json`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the URL that you mention isn't real. If you tell us the actual URL you are using, folks might be able to help.

Comment: e.g. `https://shop-usa.palaceskateboards.com/collections/hardware` I checked google dev tool under `Network` but why doesn't it show where they are making the API calls to, to fetch json data and populate the page with items?

Comment: @JoKo - What leads you to believe that palaceskateboards.com has an API?

Answer (score 0):

A `response` object has a `headers` attribute:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get("http://google.es")
    print(r.headers)
```

**Output:**

```
>> {
    'Date': 'Tue, 22 Aug 2017 00:37:13 GMT', 
    'Expires': '-1', 
    'Cache-Control': 'private, 
     max-age=0', 
     'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1',
     ...
    }
```

Comment: appreciate the response! how about as for payload for a specific route, e.g. `http://www.testsite.com/students.json`, and how do you actually find out what routes are available for a site in the first place? And why does it have e.g. `students.json`?